# How to select a parent and a filtered list of children if they exist (outer join)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, extension-methods

I can't seem to figure out what I think should be an easy task. All the posts I've found seem to be returning just the children, or don't help with the null. I have the following classes

```
 public class Parent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int isCurrent { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using EF and I want to return a specific parent and the **current** child **if** it exists. So to me this is like a Left Outer Join. I want to use method extensions as I'd like to understand how they work a bit better.

Here is some psuedo code I've tried. I cant seem to get it to return a parent even if they don't have a current child.

```
var test  = db.Parents
                .Where(p => p.ID == 1)
                .Select( p => p.Children.Where(c => c.isCurrent == 1).DefaultIfEmpty()                            
                );
```

I want it to return a Parent object and it's Children to collection to only be populated with the current child if it has one.

Comment: i'm looking around and this seems similar. But doesn't use method extensions. Not sure if there is a benefit one way or the other.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705463/linq-to-entity-framework-return-a-list-of-parents-with-only-a-subset-or-empty-co

Comment: "*and the current **child** if it exists*" Are you saying that only **one** child can be current?

Comment: I think this is the weekly incarnation of the filtered include question. Probably a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16798796/861716) (or many others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also achieve what you want if you use [Explicit Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#explicit):

```
 var parent=db.Parents.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.ID==1);
 context.Entry(parent) 
        .Collection(p => p.Children) 
        .Query() 
        .Where(c => c.isCurrent==1) 
        .Load();
```

Comment: this is interesting, i'll give it a try. this is just odd to me that this isn't simpler.

Comment: This ended up working for me. Again, this seems like a common query, still surprised it wasn't a bit simpler.

Comment: Yes, filter in the includes is still a limitation ;(

Answer (score 2):

When you use EF **navigation properties** (as you do), there is no need to think about joins - EF will do them for you. If you don't put special criteria, `one-to-many` (e.g. parent -> children) will be joined with left outer join anyway.

So all you need is to concentrate on the **desired result**. For instance, if you want to return a specific parent and it's current **children**, you can use something like this:

```
var test = (from p in db.Parents
            where p.ID == 1
            select new
            { 
                Parent = p,
                CurrentChildren = p.Children.Where(c => c.isCurrect == 1)
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you indeed need just a single current child (if exists), then something like this:

```
var test = (from p in db.Parents
            where p.ID == 1
            select new
            { 
                Parent = p,
                CurrentChild = p.Children.FirstOrDefault(c => c.isCurrect == 1)
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: so this will return an object that consists of a Parent object and a CurrentChild object. the Parent object will still have it's property of children that contain all of it's children right? I want to return one object (a Parent object) to my view... and i want it's Children to contain either only the curent child, or nothing if there there is no current child. (assume each parent can only have 1 current child.)

Comment: Then you can try the another solution. Although reusing the entity model this way is not good. The entity should not filter the content because - well, it is supposed to represent the data that is in the database.